# UIKit: UIScrollView automatically scrolling when a subview increases its width past the edge of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview

In the context of the iPhone:

I have a `UIScrollView` containing a `UIImage`. When the user taps the screen inside the `UIImage`, a `UITextField` is added where the user touched. The user can edit this `UITextField`, and the text field will automatically resize itself based on whether text was added or deleted.

When the a `UITextField` being edited increases its width, the scrollview automatically scrolls to show the increased width.

**The problem comes in because the automatic scrolling of the textfield doesn't respect the y-value of the screen**

For example, say the user added a text field to the bottom of the image. When they go to edit that text field, the keyboard will show, hiding the text field. I have code in place to scroll the screen to show the text field. The problem comes in when the user enters so much text that that text field extends past the edge of the screen. When this happens, the screen scrolls horizontally to fit the wider text, but also vertically - the vertical scrolling ends up hiding the textfield, basically nullifying anything I did to show the text field.

Code to show the text field if it's hidden by the keyboard:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    self.offset = self.contentOffset;

    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    // self.activeField is the name of the field that is the current first responder - this just adds a little bit of padding
    frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height + (self.activeField.frame.size.height * 2);

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(frame, self.activeField.frame.origin)) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(self.offset.x, self.activeField.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height + (activeField.frame.size.height * 2));
    [self setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Here is the code to increase the size of the text field:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:textField.font];
    CGSize newSize = [newString sizeWithFont:textField.font];

    // Make textField wider if we're close to running up against it
    if (newSize.width > (textField.frame.size.width - self.widthOffset)) {
        CGRect textFieldFrame = textField.frame;
        if (stringSize.width > self.widthOffset) {
            textFieldFrame.size.width += stringSize.width;
        }
        textFieldFrame.size.width += self.widthOffset;
        textField.frame = textFieldFrame;
    }

    // Shrink the textField if there is too much wasted space
    if ((textField.frame.size.width - newSize.width) > self.widthOffset) {
        CGRect textFieldFrame = textField.frame;
        textFieldFrame.size.width = newSize.width + self.widthOffset;
        textField.frame = textFieldFrame;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**The question is: How do I get the `UIScrollView` to respect the y-value of itself when automatically scrolling?**

Comment: It would help if you can provide a link with a sample project.

Answer (score 5):

Basically `setFrame` of `UIScrollView` will readjust the scrollview `offset`, done by `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary`. As that method is private and not documented, there is very little we can guess on how the adjustment will happen.
There are two ways to stop the unnecessary scrolling or wrong `offset` being set:

1) reset the `UIScrollView` `offset` after applying `setFrame`. This you can do, if you are modifying the frame of `UIScrollView` intentionally based on some calculations.

```
CGPoint oldOffset = [scrollView contentOffset];         
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(newFrame);
[scrollView setContentOffset:oldOffset];
```

2) apply `offset` changes without animation. In your `keyboardWasShown` , change 
`[self setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES]; to

[self setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];`

**Reason:** when more than one `offset` is applied with animation on, the result `offset` is ambiguous. Here the internal method(`_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary`) applies an offset change and the other one is done by your code. You can notice this if you try to log all the offsets being applied in the `UIScrollView` delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@" offset: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.conentOffset))
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Hooray Im Helping did the suggestion helped ? If not please update

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. This didn't resolve it. I overrode the setContentOffset methods and had a logging statement inside them - they weren't being called, which seems to indicate that it's a parent class doing the scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround could be to respond to the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method check to see if the `UITextField` is hidden again, then re-scroll if necessary.  Seems like a bit of a hack, but it sounds like the `UIScrollView` auto scrolling behavior is what's getting in your way, and if there's no way to directly affect it, the only option is to work around it.  There is also the disadvantage, however, that if you do this then it appears to scroll twice.

If the auto-scrolling behavior happens only when the `UITextField` expands beyond the edge of the screen, you could also move the field to stay completely visible if it looks like it's going to expand beyond the edge of the screen.

Comment: If it comes down to it, I'll resort to a hack like this, but I'd rather not. +1 for a good answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the content offset, change the scroll view's display frame.

```
- (void)keyboardWill:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    // Update the scroll view's frame to the region not covered by the keyboard.
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.fullSizedFrame.origin.x, 
                            self.fullSizedFrame.origin.y, 
                            self.fullSizedFrame.size.width, 
                            self.fullSizedFrame.size.height - keyboardSize.height);
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Set the frame back to the original frame before the keyboard was shown.
    self.frame = self.fullSizedFrame;
}
```

If you don't allow the user to change screen orientation, then fullSizedFrame could be set to the original frame of the view when it is first displayed. If changes in orientation are allowed, you'll need to calculate the appropriate value for fullSizedFrame based on the orientation.

Comment: This didn't work. I'm already offsetting the height of the UIScrollView's frame by the height of the keyboard.